# Uninstall app A that app B have a dependency in one old migration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to uninstall an app named `django-cities` but in my app "places" I have a model called `Venue`, that in the migration `0001_initial.py` had a `ForeingKey` to `cities.Subregion` model of `django-cities`.

I proceeded to delete `django-cities` of `INSTALLED_APPS` but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/d/.virtualenvs/beplay/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration places.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'cities', u'0010_adjust_unique_attributes')
```

Then I deleted those dependencies and uninstall `django-cities` and all worked for me, but if anyone else has to install the project, the `migrate` command raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Related model u'cities.Subregion' cannot be resolved
```

because I deleted from `requirements.txt` and it is still referenced in migration `0001_initial.py`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Venue',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', model_utils.fields.AutoCreatedField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False, verbose_name='created')),
                ('modified', model_utils.fields.AutoLastModifiedField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, editable=False, verbose_name='modified')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('mobile', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, null=True)),
                ('address', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('latitude', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True)),
                ('longitude', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True)),
                ('subregion', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='cities.Subregion')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Then I delete the line:

```
('subregion', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='cities.Subregion')),
```

and have another error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

I also tried to delete all `.pyc` files from the project, also I googled this error and found [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28073), but it didn't provided an answer.

Any info about this?

*Thanks and sorry for my bad English.*

Comment: try to delete this migration file and run again makemigration then migrate but firstly delete Venue table from db and also delete old venue migration file entry from django_migrations table.

Comment: I don't want to delete Venue table from db.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

*Note:* For both the following solutions you need to drop the old `Venue` table from your database before you proceed.

**The easy one:**

- Go to your `migrations/` folder and delete everything except the
  `__init__.py` file.
- Delete your app from the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations` which will recreate your migrations in the folder.
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

  *Drawbacks:* You loose your migration history if that matters (in your case I will assume that it does not matter since you refer to migration `0001`)

**The hard way:**

You will need to modify every migration file in your `migrations/` folder:

- Go to every migration file and find any reference to the app that will get uninstalled
- Delete those references:

  Example delete the line:

  ```
  ('subregion', models.ForeignKey(
                    blank=True, 
                    null=True,
                    on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                    to='cities.Subregion'
                ))
  ```

  from the Venue table fields migration.
- Delete your app from the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

  *Drawbacks:* It is complicated and prone to mistakes.

Comment: I think that the easy solution should works, but i have to be sure that all servers (staging and prod) have the last migration deployed, because i have to delete all migrations files from folder. Then when someone have to install the project, will pass without knowing. Thanks for editing and answer.
I will test it.

Comment: In the easy solution, after `makemigrations` you will have a new `0001_initial.py` which you can use thereafter!

Comment: I have a doubt here because, what happend with django_migrations records?, because when i have to do a migrations in this app, django will create a 0002 migration, that is already applied in staging and production db.

Comment: If you cannot drop your db on the stagin and productions servers you cannot solve the problem :/ . If you want to preserve your migration records, you need to follow the harder solution.