# How to completly delete a Django application which has dependencies with another app?

Tags: python, django

My Django project has several applications and I would like to delete one of them. To do that, I removed the models of this app and everything was fine, but after I removed the application from INSTALLED_APPS and its files, Django complains about dependencies with another application.

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration anotherapp.0009_entitystatus dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('apptodelete', '0002_alter_anotherapp_code')
```

I've tried to reverse migrations for the app I want to remove with the `zero` option and Django unapplied migrations, but then after I remove the files it keeps complaining because dependencies are still present in the migration files of the other application.

```
$ python manage.py migrate apptodelete zero
```

What is the proper way to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall app A that app B have a dependency in one old migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489342/uninstall-app-a-that-app-b-have-a-dependency-in-one-old-migration)

Comment: Hi, unfortunnatly it's a slightly different problem

Comment: Have you removed the obsolete references as in the mentioned answer above? That will solve your issue.

Comment: @Marco I've tried to remove the obsolete references in array `dependencies` of the migration files, but not the corresponding operations in the `operations` array. I'm afraid to break the database in which I have 16 millions objects

Comment: Removing just the dependencies on the migration files should not affect your DB

Comment: @BrianDestura it's difficut to remove dependencies because it concerns one `ManyToManyField` in 11 models. And this field still exist, the difference is that now the `ManyToManyField` point to another model. So I can't just drop this field an say it never existed